# How to create a syntax file for text files?

Tags: vim, text, formatting

I wish I could format pieces of text in standard text files.
I would like to select a phrase or a word, invoke a simple command, and format it with these formatting:

- bold
- italic
- underline
- red font color
- yellow background color

Is that possible?
(something like syntax highlighting in vim files but in my case with selected text)

I know there is a Txtfmt plugin in vim, I tried it 2 times the last years but uninstalled it every time.
This is why:

1. There is no way to visual select text and format it, you have to insert a begin code in the command-line write the text and insert an end code in the command-line.
2. You cannot copy the text because Txtfmt plugin inserts hidden formatting codes in the text
3. It is too complicate to insert a begin code and end code in the command line (after invoking a general command) and the codes are too complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a kind of markup inserted into your text. Vim operates on plain text, it has no separate meta data layer like a word processor. With syntax highlighting and the new *conceal* feature, you can partially make Vim appear to be WYSIWYG, but actually you're still operating on the raw text.

If you're fine with that limitation and want to stick with Vim for your editing tasks, I'd suggest to use an existing markup solution instead of inventing a new one from scratch. By now, there are several syntaxes to choose from, with *Markdown* probably a favorite. (It's used here on Stack Overflow, too!) With an existing syntax, you can leverage all the existing plugins / mappings / commands, and even some external tools (e.g. for converting to HTML).

Comment: I don't understand very well what you mean. You mean I  have to find a plugin to markdown the text to html?

Comment: The conversion to HTML is just an added bonus. Basically, `:setl filetype=markdown` in your buffer and start using the Markdown syntax; it allows bold, italic, and more.

Comment: Ah nice. I installed the markdown plugin (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1242) is that correct? Then I put the command ´:setl filetype=markdown´ in my commandline and can use markdown. Is that correct? But now I have ´*´ and ´#´ characters in my text isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you've got it. Vim 7.3 even already ships with Markdown syntax. And yes, you now have the markup characters, but as I had hinted at, the metadata has to go somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here is probably the simplest possible implementation of what I believe you want. It allows custom strings to be highlighted in the current buffer using the colour/style you describe. The custom strings you choose to be highlighted cannot be saved between Vim sessions.

Firstly, define the highlight group `SpecialTxt` for your bespoke highlighting:

```
au ColorScheme * hi SpecialTxt guibg=yellow guifg=red gui=bold,underline,italic
```

(note that this has to be done via an autocmd so that loading a new colourscheme doesn't overwrite it).

Now you can select any regular expression to inherit this colour using:

```
call matchadd( 'SpecialTxt', [YOUR_REGEX], 1 )
```

Or you could write a simple command to set the match:

```
command! -nargs=1 Special :call matchadd('SpecialTxt',"<args>",1)
```

Or create a map so that double clicking on a word sets it to this colouring:

```
nnoremap <silent> <2-LeftMouse> :call matchadd('SpecialTxt',expand('<cword>'),1)<CR>
```

Hope that helps. Apologies if it is not quite what you are after.

Comment: Very nice, but still can't do exactly what I want. 1) Your solution matches all words in the text as the word I double click.  2) I still can't select a piece of text (a few words or phrase) and highlight it. 3) Another problem is that after a restart all highlighting is gone. (that is not the case when I use p.e. the vim syntax).

Comment: Where do you want the store the highlighting (if not as markup in the text itself)?!